# import terms with other labels (synonyms) from CSV file using powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, term-store, csv

I have a CSV file with ~2000 terms and other labels (synonyms). There are some scripts online that do this however they show an error when they hit a term that doesn't have any other labels. Any ideas on how I can import this to Sharepoint Online term store using powershell?

Comment: Can you show the method you are using as well as the exact error you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have written a PowerShell script that gets terms and other labels from a CSV file and imports them into the Term Store. CSV formatting is shown in the GUI.
[SharePointTools GitHub](https://github.com/tb0111/SharepointTools)